# Using node-jose, how do I decrypt the data I just encrypted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, rsa, jose

I am trying to implement simple `JOSE` `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions using [`node-jose`](https://github.com/cisco/node-jose).

My code is as follows (written using Node 8.2.1)

```
const { JWE } = require('node-jose');

const jose = (publicKey, privateKey) => {
  async function encrypt(raw) {
    if (!raw) throw new Error('Missing raw data.')
    const buffer = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(raw));
    return JWE.createEncrypt(publicKey).update(buffer).final();
  }

  async function decrypt(encrypted) {
    if (!encrypted) throw new Error('Missing encrypted data.')
    const buffer = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(encrypted));
    return JWE.createDecrypt(privateKey).decrypt(buffer);
  }

  return { encrypt, decrypt }
}

module.exports = jose;
```

I generate an RSA keypair using [`generate-rsa-keypair`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-rsa-keypair).

So testing via this code the encryption side of things works fine

```
const { JWK } = require('node-jose');
const keygen = require('generate-rsa-keypair');
const jose = require('./src/utils/jose');

const rawKeys = keygen();

const makeKey = pem => JWK.asKey(pem, 'pem');

async function start() {
  const publicKey = await makeKey(rawKeys.public)
  const privateKey = await makeKey(rawKeys.private)

  const raw = {
    iss: 'test',
    exp: new Date().getTime() + 3600,
    sub: {
      test: 'This is a test',
    },
  };

  const { encrypt, decrypt } = jose(publicKey, privateKey);

  return encrypt(raw).then(encrypted => decrypt(encrypted));
}

return start().then((result) => {
  console.log('decrypted', result)
}, (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

the `encrypted` result is

```
{
  recipients: [ { encrypted_key: 'ciNiK6Unq30zCAXxIl2Dx9b8bZAi79qbpL1yUCwTFnSghFLrIZ11_D2ozt5on3r3ThUu96oDLZPcNShbqWPMV49NvQAsSNGdemhgzmTt3Lf3rJn1YiqvJvqf5NIXdmzjdoEZi-d9224mGpZGVKtIIFeT6-0hYgm5zNqq_aF_X2jy5IiF-mAGspNdXIk_KXPrTVbnU-XL9J5aAoG2Lp51Te1WzGA4Fjg4Ve5ZTzH6TLlQ5R5Ob_14liK-INrSi3armwXrtMgJcTmI_4oBtORtZp8AjaXzecFO_GzifvRVCSKx2vmpy9KaECpskMhZBHVx9RX9cvGKh7hq3Y7vsUucZw' } ],
  protected: 'eyJhbGciOiJSU0EtT0FFUCIsImtpZCI6IldLWS1ONDRXM2RnanA4U2ZxSlp3TldqV3AzUG1XZ29UczhjRDh3eWNSUWciLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0',
  iv: 'wvqir2ewtQPfDHQtzl6IUg',
  ciphertext: 'ZwIrL_3739LI17rh3gWDUA6lXIL7ewkSh54FO_RwumC0qh9B0DcAr8RyXsfPbW19cV4u7SbZNSRP6B8qNOTy-2iENlqBISfE_kolDt8g5sg',
  tag: 'z8nwrJfRgOi1hYMBI9lGeQ'
}
```

but when I try to decrypt that I get

```
Error: no key found
  at processKey (node_modules/node-jose/lib/jwe/decrypt.js:157:22)
```

There are very few examples of using `node-jose` so I am unsure of the following

1. I am assuming I ought to be decrypting with the private key. But that's just an assumption. None of the examples show use of public/private key pairs, just a single key.
2. I'm assuming that the results of the encryption can just be strringified and turned into a buffer and passed into `decrypt` but perhaps that's not the case.

How does this really work?

Comment: What's the algorithm that's used here and how do I chose one?

Comment: In this example I used RSA from https://www.npmjs.com/package/generate-rsa-keypair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When using public/private key pairs, the `private` key is used to decrypt and the `public` key is used to encrypt.
2. The input to `JWEDecrypter.decrypt()` is the promised output from `JWEEncrypter.final()`.

Change your `decrypt` function to:

```
async function decrypt(encrypted) {
  if (!encrypted) throw new Error('Missing encrypted data.')
  return JWE.createDecrypt(privateKey).decrypt(encrypted);
}
```